# Bash: same version, syntax works on Fedora and not on Manjaro. Why?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, fedora, manjaro

I `source` this little script to simplify building some code:

```
function buildprog () {
    local builddir="/home/$USER/prog/build"
    echo "$builddir"
    # max threads - 2
    local np=6
    local old_wd=$(pwd)
    local rel="Release"
    local deb="Debug"
    case $1 in
        "all"); buildprog $rel & buildprog $deb;;
        "$rel")
            cd "${builddir}/$rel"; make -j $np;;
        "$deb")
            cd "${builddir}/$rel"; make -j $np;;
        *)
            echo "Build option '$1' unknown.";;
    esac
    cd $old_wd
}
complete -W "all Debug Release" buildprog
```

On my one machine, Fedora 36 KDE, this works with both `bash` and `zsh`. On my other machine, with Manjaro KDE (Kernel v.5.15.19-1), it reports a syntax error:

```
bash: ./testscript.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: ./testscript.sh: line 12: `               "all");'
```

Both systems report `bash --version` as `5.1.16(1)-release`, with only one difference:

`(x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` on Fedora vs `(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` on Manjaro.

What could be the cause, that on one machine, the single-line version is allowed, while it is considered a syntax error on the other?

With `zsh` (v.5.8.1 on Fedora, v.5.9 on Manjaro), it works on both machines.

I'm quite new to Linux shell scripting, so please be gentle ;)

Comment: this - `"all");` - generates the same error for me (`bash 4.4.12`); are you 100% sure the system where this runs really does have `"all");` or does it have `"all")` (sans the `;`)?  or maybe on the system where the code runs you have something like `"all") cd ...;` (`cd` between `"all")` and `;`)? have you run a `diff` of the actual code from both hosts to verify it's 100% identical?

Comment: I had `git push`ed it to a gitlab repo from the Fedora machine, then `git clone`d it on the Manjaro sys, so it should really be the same file... Originally, all three options were one-liners. Definitely all have the `;` after the option. And that works just fine on Fedora's `bash` (and on `zsh` on both).

Comment: That you attribute the issue to single-line *vs* multiline format suggests that you think the semicolon (`;`) and newline characters are interchangeable in shell syntax.  They are not.  There are several contexts where both can serve the same purpose, but others where they cannot.  However, that does not explain why one Bash build / configuration rejects the code and the other accepts it.

Comment: Do we need all the stuff in your code? Can you make an __minimal__ [MCVE]? Does `case a in all); ;; esac` not/does generate a syntax error? Does `bash -c 'case a in all); ;; esac'` reproduces it? And anyway, making sure, you are specifically asking the question _why_ - you do know you can remove the `;` in your code and get on with your life?

Comment: Single line version was easier in my use case, because it's part of a larger script, which allows to configure either or both build types, and then removes the unused cases.

Comment: `"$all"); ` is a syntax error, as the error message clearly says. Remove the semicolon.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I thought they're the same. I'll have to look that up then.

Comment: @dan that's not the question

Comment: @RL-S yes, but OP is indicating that `;` is used on one platform but not the other. OP: Is that the case? Or are you sourcing the exact script above and recieving no error on one platform?

Comment: Exact same script, no error on one platform.

Answer (score 0):

Revised based comments:

Source of the issue is extra semicolon after the "all")

```
case $1 in
# BAD       "all"); buildprog $rel & buildprog $deb;;
            "all") buildprog $rel & buildprog $deb;;
        "$rel")
         ...
```

No good explanation why some versions are forgiving. In theory, empty statements (e.g., '; ;' ) will result in syntax error.

Comment: This would be good practice, but it is not related to the syntax error (which is a genuine error in the code presented).

Comment: Will do, was an oversight. Thanks. Not the answer though.

Comment: @RL-S the error is reported on line 12, which is "cd "${builddi" ... Is there anything else in the script that you did not include ?

Comment: Out of curiousity: why do you include a ';' after "all") ; ? Bash might not allow empty statement there. You do not have the same in "$rel") and "$deb").

Comment: This is completely unneccesary, `$1` is identical to `"$1"` in this context. `"$all");` is clearly the cause of OP's error.

Comment: Revised answer based on followup discussion.